Is there any way to run segmentation model SAM2?
I would like to run sam2: https://github.com/facebookresearch/segment-anything-2.
Does ServiceConnect allow us to connect to meta.ai or llama 3.1 to do things like this https://aidemos.meta.com?

If I were going to solve this, I'd probably do it through a 3rd party API, e.g., as offered by Replicate.  Will cost you a few pesos (you will need to set up an API key), but easier than doing any kind of software install.
